# What is a best practice for security in Laravel with authentication?

Tags: laravel, security, authentication

I am doing the security of my website and I'm using the Auth module that Laravel provides, as you know there are a lot of ways to perform security, you can use the middleware Auth to protect Routes, you can protect your controllers and views with the same module, that is what I'm doing right now.

I want to know from someone has experience hacking this system if just protecting my the routes where I want more security is more than enough, or I should keep protecting controllers and views that I don't want other people have access.

It is a simple question and I don't know if I should better put this question in the meta stack overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as far as i know, you can just protect routes. Routes are the way that people is going to access your application, they cant have access to the plain controller code. Using the auth you are going to create an "authentication" session, this is, you are going to protect the specific routes and give access just to an authorized person, this person is going to have an user/password to have access to your route. This is enough as route wise, but you (laravel takes care of it for you) have to be aware of sql injection and other stuff, thats the way that hackers will be able to have access to your information.

Comment: Exactly. Laravel is very secure out of the box and prevents sql injection.

Comment: Actually laravel (and other frameworks) is very good, it takes care of a lot of things that you wouldnt (99% of the time) do it properly, or they do it in a better way that you would.

Comment: Thank you, I'm using Route::resource that provides REST routes, that is why I said I needed to protect my controllers, by example, I don't want that an unauthorized person has access to the /module/create route so I saw it in two ways, protecting the route or protecting in the controller, as didn't want to protect the route /module or in the controller the index() function, I protected the others.

Comment: you could use a token based authentication for it.